# How to go to different matching entry in vim's help

Tags: help-system

Example: I tried finding out about [`foldclose`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711212/vim-auto-fold-when-leaving-fold) because it sounded strange to me that it isn't a binary setting but still only knows the value `"all"`.  I typed `:h foldclose` and landed on a description of the command `:foldc[lose]`. How do I find the help entry that describes the vim setting `foldclose`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `:help 'foldclose` to get the help for the option foldclose.
Find details about possible contexts in `:help help-context`

Comment: Not exactly what I asked for, but great nonetheless and solves the example problem

Answer (score 1):

Use `helpgrep` and then navigate through the matches either directly in the quickfix window that is opened or use `:lnext` and `:lprevious`